# Out Of Memory with pagerView Monodorid

Tags: xamarin.android, out-of-memory, viewpagerindicator

I need a hand on pagerView. When I use the pagerview after a hundred pages the application gives me error 'out of memory'. I need a method to destroy the view because it keeps me in memory all (from first to last).
In view memorize 4 boxes made ​​by me with an image (which does not change) and two buttons.

this is my adapter:

```
namespace ProvaViewPager
{
    public class FragmentAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        int mCount;
        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        public FragmentAdapter (FragmentManager fm) : base (fm)
        {
            mCount = 200;
            mFragmentManager = fm;
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem (int position)
        {
            return new SwiftView (position);
        }

        public override int Count {
            get {
                return mCount;  
            }   
        }
```

use the method distroy? but how?

Message in debug:

> Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. Clamp target GC heap from 49.446MB to 48.000MB Clamp
>   target GC heap from 49.847MB to 48.000MB Clamp target GC heap from
>   49.860MB to 48.000MB Clamp target GC heap from 49.859MB to 48.000MB Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 712-byte allocation Clamp
>   target GC heap from 49.859MB to 48.000MB Out of memory on a 712-byte
>   allocation. Clamp target GC heap from 49.874MB to 48.000MB Clamp
>   target GC heap from 49.874MB to 48.000MB Forcing collection of
>   SoftReferences for 964-byte allocation Clamp target GC heap from
>   49.874MB to 48.000MB Out of memory on a 964-byte allocation.Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.EvaluatorException:
>   Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>
> in Mono.Debugging.Soft.MethodCall.get_ReturnValue()
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftEvaluationContext.RuntimeInvoke(MethodMirror
>   method, Object target, Value[] values)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CallToString(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, Object obj)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, Object obj)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext
>   gctx, Object obj)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, Object obj)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj,
>   ObjectValueFlags flags)
>
> in
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj,
>   ObjectValueFlags flags) Clamp target GC heap from 49.874MB to 48.000MB
>   Clamp target GC heap from 49.874MB to 48.000MB Forcing collection of
>   SoftReferences for 964-byte allocation Clamp target GC heap from
>   49.874MB to 48.000MB Out of memory on a 964-byte allocation. Clamp target GC heap from 49.874MB to 48.000MB

Sorry for the bad English

Comment: How do you exactly instantiate your ImageViews in SwiftView? You might be loading huge images into the memory which makes you run out of memory. Please supply some code for SwiftView.

Answer (score 0):

Then create a ViewPager containing a box, composed of an image and written ..... each page is composed of 4 box.
This is my code for create box:

```
 namespace ProvaViewPager.Widget.CatalogoBox

{

    public class CatalogoBox : RelativeLayout

    {

        private LayoutInflater _mInflater;

        private LinearLayout _mBox;



        private void Initialize ()

        {

        }



        public CatalogoBox (IntPtr doNotUse, JniHandleOwnership transfer)

            : base(doNotUse, transfer)

        {

        }



        public CatalogoBox (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)

            : base(context, attrs)

        {

            InternalCtor (context, attrs);

        }



        public CatalogoBox (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)

            : base(context, attrs, defStyle)

        {

            InternalCtor (context, attrs);

        }



        ~CatalogoBox ()

        {

            Dispose (false);

        }





        private void InternalCtor (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)

        {

            _mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);

            _mBox = (LinearLayout)_mInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.CatalogoBox, null);

            AddView (_mBox);

        }

    }

}
```

and here (class SwiftView : Fragment) we recall:

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        TextView TxtCDPAR;

        TextView TxtDEPAR;

        TextView TxtPrezzo;

        TextView TxtPz;



        ImageView ImageDisp;

        ImageView ImgFreccia;

        ImageView ImgIncrementa;

        ImageView ImgDecrementa;

        ImageView ImageItem;

        EditText Quantita;

        ImageView ImageProduct;

        LinearLayout BoxAddProdotto;

        View v = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.PageViewXml, container, false);

        if (v != null) {

            #region BOX1

            var BoxProdotto1 = v.FindViewById<ProvaViewPager.Widget.CatalogoBox.CatalogoBox> (Resource.Id.CatalogoBox1);

            TxtCDPAR = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_TxtCodiceProdotto);

            TxtDEPAR = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_DescrProdotto);

            ImageView ImagetItem1 = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImageProduct) as ImageView;

            TxtPz = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_NumeroPezzi);

            TxtPrezzo = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_TxtPrezzo);

            BoxAddProdotto = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.BoxAddProdotto);

            ImageDisp = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImgDisp);

            ImgFreccia = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImgFreccia);

            ImgIncrementa = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageIncrementa);

            ImgDecrementa = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageDecrementa);

            Quantita = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editNumerico);

            ImageProduct = BoxProdotto1.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImageProduct);

            TxtPz.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;



            ImagetItem1.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.imagespiaggia);



            #endregion



            #region BOX2

            var BoxProdotto2 = v.FindViewById<ProvaViewPager.Widget.CatalogoBox.CatalogoBox> (Resource.Id.CatalogoBox2);

            TxtCDPAR = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_TxtCodiceProdotto);

            TxtDEPAR = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_DescrProdotto);

            ImageItem = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImageProduct) as ImageView;

            TxtPz = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_NumeroPezzi);

            TxtPrezzo = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.CAT_TxtPrezzo);

            BoxAddProdotto = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.BoxAddProdotto);

            ImageDisp = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImgDisp);

            ImgFreccia = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImgFreccia);

            ImgIncrementa = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageIncrementa);

            ImgDecrementa = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageDecrementa);

            Quantita = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editNumerico);

            ImageProduct = BoxProdotto2.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.CAT_ImageProduct);

            TxtPz.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;



            ImageItem.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.feliximage);



            #endregion
```

This is Adapter:

```
namespace ProvaViewPager
```

{

```
public class FragmentAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter

{

    int mCount;

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;



    public FragmentAdapter (FragmentManager fm) : base (fm)

    {

        mCount = 200;

        mFragmentManager = fm;

    }



    public override Fragment GetItem (int position)

    {

        return new SwiftView (position);

    }



    public override int Count {

        get {

            return mCount;  

        }   

    }



    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)

    {
        return base.InstantiateItem (container, position);

    }



    public override void DestroyItem (ViewGroup collection, int position, Java.Lang.Object view)

    {

        base.DestroyItem(collection,position,view);



    }

}
```

}